# How can I store a link in a variable and open it using os.system()

Tags: python, python-3.x, browser, os.system

I want to make an app in Python to open links the user assigned to buttons. For that I have to assign links to variables and open them. I tried opening them with the webbrowser module, but they would open in Microsoft Edge and not in the default browser, so I decided to use os.system(), but I can't seem to succeed in opening the links in the variables.

I have tried Googling this issue, but seems like no one even thought about using os.system() to open URLs.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import platform
link1 = "example.com"
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    os.system("start \"\" "link1)
elif platform.system() == "Linux":
    os.system("xdg-open \"\" "link1)
elif platform.system() == "Darwin":
    os.system("open \"\" "link1)
```

Running this results in a Windows error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using the variable name as a string.

Use something like this:

```
os.system("start \"\" "+link1)
```

Alternatively this should also work:

```
os.system("start \"\" {}").format(link1)
```

I just tried your Darwin approach on my macOS system. Im not quite sure what you are trying to achieve with `\"\"`. I'm sorry, if I missed something. On my system it works with `open http://google.com`.